# Rails 4 + ActiveRecord: How to merge data from 2 models?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models, I would need to load data from them, put the loaded data to oen variable and then iterate through it (the models models have different attributes) – something like this:

```
cars = Car.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
bikes = Bike.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)

@data = cars + bikes
```

and then in model, I'd like to do something like this:

```
@data.order('created_at DESC).each do...
```

But the thing is that sorting like on the line above doesn't work. How to sort data from two models according to the column `created_at`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution:**

Use Rails STI (Single Table Inheritance). In order to use it, you would need to create new model (and table) called `Vehicle` and then you could call `Vehicle.order('created_at DESC').limit(20)`. Your model classes would look like then:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base; end
class Car < Vehicle; end
class Bike < Vehicle; end
```

**Second solution:**

```
cars = Car.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
bikes = Bike.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
@data = (cars + bikes).sort_by{|vehicle| vehicle.created_at}.reverse
```

It does not involve any changes to your model schema however needs additional computations by server side.

To iterate over such collection, if these models differ:

```
@data.each do |vehicle|
  if vehicle.respond_to?(:sold_at)
    vehicle.sold_at
  end
  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer `blelump`. When I try it, I get this error in the view: `undefined method 'sold_at' for #<Car:0x007fe988072e38>`. 'sold_at' is an attribute from the model `Bike` and is not in the model `Car`. Any tip how to fight with this issue? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, just playing with it.